# Moving objects along individual normals

Tags: transforms, normals

So here I am making this simple dice in Blender 2.82a, and it's going swell, but these pips need holes to live in.

I think I should move all the pips inwards a little bit and use boolean difference to cut holes. I set the transformation orientation to "normal" and transform pivot point to "individual origins", but sadly that doesn't seem to apply to moving (I tried pressing G and then Z, and also tried pressing G and Z Z but all the pips just move in the same direction).

Is there a way to move all of these pips inward along their normals, or should I just quit trying to optimize my life and do them one by one?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might sound like a non-answer, but you hit the nail on the head with your last sentence in my experience. I can think of a few ways to do *something* like what you want, but they all require more effort than <kbd>g</kbd>, <kbd>z</kbd>, [some integer], then repeating on x and y.

Comment: Guess I'm preparing for the moment where someone holds a gun to my head and demands me to move 1000 objects along their normals within 10 seconds.

Comment: The only reason I even know about the grab and axis keys is exactly the same impulse :p Don't feel bad